# Error after running latest TeXLive tlmgr update - Missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: texlive, revtex

After running tlmgr update --all (I hadn't run it in a while) this code (from the dtx files all version of REVTeX 4 (version 4.2 is coming!)):

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname package@font\endcsname\@undefined\else
\expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter{\csname package@font\endcsname}%
\fi
```

gives

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded   format=latex 2017.12.21)  22 DEC 2017 16:56
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**foo.tex
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.15> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \package@font 
l.3 \fi

?
```

This error doesn't happen if I run under older TeXLive installations and I didn't encounter until I ran the update. How can I figure out what broke?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: I just tried pdflatex revtex4.1.dtx in a texlive 2016 setup (the oldest I have to hand) and it gave this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This test

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname package@font\endcsname\@undefined
```

is never going to test true as `\csname ljhgjghlj\encdname` returns a csname `\let` to `\relax` so you always do

```
\RequirePackage\expandafter{\csname package@font\endcsname}%
```

even when it's not defined, in which case you get an error.

Comment: revtex4.dtx has the correct test against `\relax` but revtex4-1.dtx has this test against `\@undefined` which could never have worked unless you define `\@undefined` to be defined, which is weird.

Comment: Can you imagine why the class doesn't use `\@ifundefined{package@font}`? I can't.

Comment: Thanks David. I confess to being a bit too quick to post. This works under my much older (2014) TeXLive installation, but I guess when I was working on this under my initial 2017 install, I was only running tex and not latex to create the generated files and not create the formatted PDF docs. I’m just not sure at this point. Anyway, i will just remove the offending code or perhaps switch to the suggestion by egreg. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkDoyle it could only work if you had some package that had erroneously defined `\@ifundefined` or that always ensured that `\package@font`  was defined. The code fragment as posted in your question would always have given an error.